# How to read/extract climate model data in .asc file format by using Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have downloaded some global climate model data from an opensource website. But, these data are in .asc file format. How could I read/extract these data using Python? Anything in Numpy?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the data? Do you know exactly what an .asc file is? It doesn't make much sense to convert it to any kind of python data structure. You're much better off dealing with it natively

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/71873 information on .asc format from the GIS SO.

Comment: have you tried [karta](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/karta/0.2.4). [More docs here](http://ironicmtn.com/karta/).

Comment: @ hpaulj, I supposed these are like netCDF data. It seems they are not.

Comment: @Slater. I downloaded the precipitation data from this website [http://www.ccafs-climate.org/data/]  and wanted to read the data for time series analysis.

Comment: @Mark, I am not familiar with karta. I will have a look. Thank you all.

Comment: What open source site did you get the data from? They should have documentation on the format of the data and how to consume it. Try opening the file and reading it, maybe you can figure it out the format.

Comment: Hi @Mark, I have got it from Kersten's answer. These are mostly like text files. :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

.asc means you likely chose the **ASCII Grid** download option from CCAFS. These are simple text files with a 6 line header containing the geographic information.

If you just want to load the data into a numpy array you can use the `loadtxt` function. You just have to skip the first 6 rows which contain the header.

```
import numpy as np
ascii_grid = np.loadtxt("bio_1.asc", skiprows=6)
```

If you want to preserve the geographic information in the ASCII Grid while working in Python there is a [tutorial by Joel Lawhead over at Geospatial Python](http://geospatialpython.com/2013/12/python-and-elevation-data-ascii-grid.html).

Comment: and you could easily load the first 6 lines to automatically get the lat and long to match your numpy array indices