# Reading .ASC format file in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am dealing with a certain .asc file format which contains some data regarding weight and height. I just want to find BMI indexes of people with this data. I am not able to make sense of the dataframe formed after reading the data.

```
import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_table("data.asc")
```

I am not able to make sense of the result that I get. Please help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/30117567/8878627

Comment: `.asc` suggests that it's simply an ASCII text file; can you please [edit] to include a short snippet so we can see what the format looks like? (Please, not as a comment, an image, a link to Google Drive, or interstellar coordinates of a galaxy which resembles the contents of the file in the sixth derivative. Plain text, in the question itself.)

Comment: ASC is a generic filename extension that really just means it's a text file. You can possibly read it with pandas, but you need to show some of the file content, it something similar to it. It's impossible to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to work with a file with the extension "asc". My solution was the following:

1. I opened the file with a text editor and check the separator for the file, then transform it into a spreadsheet. In my case, I turned the document into a "csv" file.
2. After that I ran:

   ```py
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.read_csv('path to your file')
   ```

Comment: It's not just the separator though, there could be header lines or other stuff that needs dealing with.